# Raspberry Pi Ant+ to Btle Bridge

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to know if it is possible to program a raspberry pi to receive ANT+ from a usb dongle and broadcast that data in the form of bluetooth to an iphone?  I know there is a device called a WASP CABLE that does this already and cost around 60.00

I have the raspberry pi 3 and a usb ant+ dongle already and would rather not purchase another device to make this work.

[WASP CABLE](http://www.titaniumgeek.com/gear-reviews/hands-on-with-wasp-cable-ant-bridge-on-zwift-ios-zwift-gear-test/)

Comment: Here looking to do the same!